# Django Send Email with forbidden access permission

Tags: python, django, sockets, smtp, django-email

I am now using Django as the backend API endpoints and I want to send out email to for notification.

settings.py

```
#Email settings
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_USE_SSL = False
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'test.'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'test@gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
```

views.py

```
    def GetEmailNotification(request):
       subject = "This is a test email"
       message = "This is a test message"
       from_email = 'test@gmail.com'
       send_mail(subject, message, from_email, ['test@gmail.com'], fail_silently=False)
       return HttpResponse("sent!")
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [path('emailNotification/', GetEmailNotification)]
```

But when I did the get request. it gave the error

```
OSError: [WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions
```

After I changed the port in the setting.py from 457 to 1000, it gave the error of

```
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
```

How to solve this issue? Any ideas?

Comment: looks like you have blocked port ? on which port you are running the app ? is any other method/page in your app is working fine or this is happening with each page of project?

Comment: The django backend is running on port 8000, I tested the url in postman and it gave this error.

Comment: check my answer and have a try.

Comment: can you share Django version ?

Comment: Django 2.0.7 ....

Comment: please check updated answer for urls.py.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run your Django-server on different port like example : 8080

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080
```

and try to hit the same URL with postman

and also modify urls.py

```
path('emailNotification', views.GetEmailNotification, name='GetEmailNotification'),
```

also check if you have CRF enabled and that is preventing API call (security issue shouldn't be disabled on production).

```
#'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
```